# T test and permutation testing

Tags: r, hypothesis-test

I have a data frame which looks like this. There are 2 separate groups and 5 different variables.

```
df <- read.table(text="Group   var1    var2    var3    var4    var5
1           3   5   7   3   7
1           3   7   5   9   6
1           5   2   6   7   6
1           9   5   7   0   8
1           2   4   5   7   8
1           2   3   1   6   4 
2           4   2   7   6   5
2           0   8   3   7   5
2           1   2   3   5   9
2           1   5   3   8   0
2           2   6   9   0   7
2           3   6   7   8   8
2           10  6   3   8   0", header = TRUE)
```

I'm calculating the significance of each variable for distinguishing between the 2 groups using the T test (as below). However I'd like to implement permutation testing to calculate the p values as this is quite a small dataset. What is the best method for doing this in R?

```
t(sapply(df[-1], function(x) 
 unlist(t.test(x~df$Group)[c("p.value")])))
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is your data significantly larger and you need a performance boost?

Comment: My actual dataset is quite small so I'd like to do permutation testing in order to try and validate what I'm actually finding